# how to call a variable in an array

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am new to Node.js and Google Cloud Functions. I am trying to generate a thumbnail once an image is uploaded into Firebase storage and it works great. However there is a small problem that I could not get around

```
 const thumbarray = [];
 exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object('{pushId}/ProductImages').onFinalize((object, context) => {

// [START eventAttributes]
const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.
const resourceState = object.resourceState; // The resourceState is 'exists' or 'not_exists' (for file/folder deletions).
const metageneration = object.metageneration; // Number of times metadata has been generated. New objects have a value of 1.


const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath);
const fileName0 = path.basename(filePath);


var fileName = fileName0.split("*")[1];
var thumbname = fileName0.split("*")[2];  // thumbnail 1 or 2 or 3
thumbarray.push(thumbname);



const thumbFilePath = path.normalize(path.join(fileDir, `${THUMB_PREFIX}${fileName}`));
const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
const tempLocalThumbFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), thumbFilePath);

console.log("the file name is ", fileName);


console.log("this is the object ", object);
// [END eventAttributes]

// [START stopConditions]
// Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
    console.log('This is not an image.');
    return null;
}


// Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.
if (fileName.startsWith(THUMB_PREFIX)) {
    console.log('Already a Thumbnail.');
    return null;
}

// Download file from bucket.
const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
const file = bucket.file(filePath);
const thumbFile = bucket.file(thumbFilePath);




const metadata = {
    contentType: contentType,
};
// Create the temp directory where the storage file will be downloaded.
return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
    // Download file from bucket.
    return file.download({
        destination: tempLocalFile
    });
}).then(() => {
    console.log('The file has been downloaded to', tempLocalFile);
    // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
    return spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-thumbnail', `${THUMB_MAX_WIDTH}x${THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT}>`, tempLocalThumbFile], {
        capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']
    });
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempLocalThumbFile);
    // Uploading the Thumbnail.
    return bucket.upload(tempLocalThumbFile, {
        destination: thumbFilePath,
        metadata: metadata
    });
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail uploaded to Storage at', thumbFilePath);
    // Once the image has been uploaded delete the local files to free up disk space.
    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
    fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalThumbFile);
    // Get the Signed URLs for the thumbnail and original image.
    const config = {
        action: 'read',
        expires: '03-01-2500',
    };
    return Promise.all([
        thumbFile.getSignedUrl(config),
        file.getSignedUrl(config),
    ]);
}).then((results) => {
    console.log('Got Signed URLs.');
    // var thumbname = fileName0.split("*")[2];

    const thumbname = thumbarray[0];
    console.log('the thumbname from array is ...', thumbname);
    const thumbResult = results[0];
    const originalResult = results[1];
    const thumbFileUrl = thumbResult[0];
    const fileUrl = originalResult[0];
    // Add the URLs to the Database
    return admin.database().ref('Listings/' + fileName).update({
        path: fileUrl,
        thumbname: thumbFileUrl // I want thumbname to be thumbname 1 or 2 or 3 
    });
}).then(() => console.log('Thumbnail URLs saved to database.'));
});
```

I defined thumbname earlier in the code

```
 var thumbname = fileName0.split("*")[2];  // thumbnail 1 or 2 or 3
```

I want to call it later on at the end of the code here

```
  thumbname: thumbFileUrl // I want thumbname to be thumbname 1 or 2 or 3
```

but it's not getting the right variable( i.e thumbnail 1) instead it reads thumbname as a string not variable. How can I get the variable to be called here? Any help will be appriciated

Comment: There're different `thumbname` and `thumbFileUrl` variables declared in the second to last `.then()` promise. Did you check if you're referencing the correct variables? Also, the `thumbname` in `thumbname: thumbFileUrl` has NOTHING to do with the `thumbname` variables; it's just the key to an Object property.

Comment: They are the same thumbname. The key to the object property is what is not always "thumbname", it can be "thumbnail 1" or "thumbnail 2". The thumnail name are stored in thumbname variable. That is what I am trying to get.

Comment: They are the same @DamodarDahal